# Having problems with implementing Ledge grab

Tags: 2d, game-development, gdscript

```
   
   
   if $LedgeDetectorh.is_colliding()&&$LedgeDetectorh.get_collider() is Ledge:
       if !$LedgeDetectorv.is_colliding():
           isLedgeGrabbed = true
   elif !$LedgeDetectorh2.is_colliding():
       isLedgeGrabbed = false
   if isLedgeGrabbed:
       
       Motion = Vector2.ZERO
       
       applyGravity = false
       $LedgeDetectorv.enabled = false
       $LedgeDetectorh2.enabled = false
       
       if immediateInputLogic:
           onLedgeGrabbedIdle = false
           $LedgeTimer.start(5)
       
       else:
           onLedgeGrabbedIdle = true
           
       if onLedgeGrabbedIdle:
           Motion.y =0
           Motion.x = 0
           
           if $LedgeTimer.time_left ==0:
               
               if $LedgeDetectorh2.enabled == true:
                   
                   self.position.direction_to($LedgeDetectorh2.get_collision_point())* 50
               
       elif $LedgeTimer.time_left > 0:
           print("works")
           Motion.y = lerp(Motion.y, -400,1)
           Motion.x = lerp(Motion.x, 100 * direction,0.2)
   elif !$LedgeDetectorh2.is_colliding():
       $LedgeDetectorh.enabled = true
       $LedgeDetectorv.enabled = true
       $LedgeDetectorh2.enabled = true
       applyGravity = true
```

problem is as far as I can tell raycast2ds keep on getting enabled and false all the time made some conditions to only enable them if is not colliding with wall still no luck

Comment: Hey there it's mine pleasure to be here, trying to learn and contribute to the community as much as I can when I'm myself at that level. thanks for the precaution is it fine now?

Comment: here's a gif that explains the problem briefly https://imgur.com/a/jgERYaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say keep your multiple `RayCast2D` enabled. If your goal is to optimize the code, this is not the way (for that I'd suggest [`intersect_ray`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physics2ddirectspacestate.html#class-physics2ddirectspacestate-method-intersect-ray)). However, first let us make sure it works correctly.

*By the way, you can use `is_stopped()` instead of `time_left`.*

I'm confused about what approach you are going for. I'm aware of a few approaches to do this:

1. Two horizontal `RayCast2D`, both horizontal, and parallel to each other, checking for the wall. One on the bottom and one on the top. If the bottom one detects a wall, but the top one does not, it means it there is a ledge. *This is easy to implement, but does not give much information for animation/Inverse kinematics. You know there is a ledge, but not exactly where.*
2. Again two `RayCast2D`. This time one is horizontal and detects a wall, and the other one is vertical, casting downwards from the top, and it is trying to find the floor where the player would stand if it climbed up the ledge. With the catch that you should position the vertical `RayCast2D` according to the position where the horizontal collided. *Which reminds me, use `force_update_transform` and `force_raycast_update` if you moved the RayCast2D from code.*
3. With collaboration from ledge objects. You can add small `Area2D`s for each ledge on the designer, and if the player overlaps any of them, then it is on a ledge.
4. Again with collaboration from ledge objects, but this time they are floor extensions that the player can check with a `RayCast2D` directly upwards. So an horizontal `ReyCast2D` finds the wall, and a vertical `RayCast2D` finds the floor extensions that identifies the ledge. *Taking care of collision layers and masks so these floor extensions do not interfere with anything else.*

Having these ledge objects is great for animation (in particular in 3D), since you can get very precise positions for that inverse kinematics. But it means that a designer has to make sure they are placed in the world, and in any area without them the player can't climb. *Don't tell me, you have seen that in games.*

You already have ledge objects, don't you? I think it would be easy to add an `Area2D` to them and use the third approach I listed above, which does not require `RayCast2D` at all.

So the `Ledge` would be or have an `Area2D` that connects `"body_entered"` to the `Area2D` itself. When the signal triggers, the `Area2D` will get a reference to the object that entered. Make sure it is the player, and call a method on it, letting it know there is a ledge it can grab (it can pass its own position as parameter so the player script can snap to it).

---

**Addendum**

Let us go over the third approach as described. There will be an `Area2D` for each ledge. This `Area2D` will have a script, and the class name is `Ledge`:

```
class_name Ledge extends Area2D
```

> So the `Ledge` would be or have an `Area2D` that connects `"body_entered"` to the `Area2D` itself. When the signal triggers, the `Area2D` will get a reference to the object that entered.

*I'll do the signal connections from code. As to avoid any mistake in connecting it via the editor.*

```
class_name Ledge extends Area2D

func _ready() -> void:
    connect("body_entered", self, "_on_body_entered")

func _on_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    pass
```

Here `body` is the reference of the body that entered.

> Make sure it is the player

Hopefully you can use collision masks and layers to narrow the checks. I don't know how you would identify the player, but I'll venture to guess it has a class name `Player`, so I can check like this:

```
class_name Ledge extends Area2D

func _ready() -> void:
    connect("body_entered", self, "_on_body_entered")

func _on_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    if body is Player:
        pass
```

> and call a method on it, letting it know there is a ledge it can grab (it can pass its own position as parameter so the player script can snap to it).

So you can either have the `Area2D` pass itself, or pass its global position. In the code below go for the global position. I'll call the method it calls on player `on_ledge`, which also means we can check for the method with `has_method` (I'll replace the check for that).

```
class_name Ledge extends Area2D

func _ready() -> void:
    connect("body_entered", self, "_on_body_entered")

func _on_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    if body.has_method("on_legde"):
        body.on_ledge(global_position)
```

And you would, of course, add that method to the player script:

```
func on_ledge(ledge_global_position:Vector2) -> void:
    print(ledge_global_position)
```

There you can snap the player position, play an animation or whatever is appropriate.

---

Perhaps passing the `Area2D` itself is better, we could do this:

```
class_name Ledge extends Area2D

func _ready() -> void:
    connect("body_entered", self, "_on_body_entered")

func _on_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    if body.has_method("on_legde"):
        body.on_ledge(self)
```

And then on the player:

```
var current_ledge:Area2D = null

func on_ledge(ledge:Area2D) -> void:
    current_ledge = ledge

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if not is_instance_valid(current_ledge) or not current_ledge.overlaps_body(self):
        current_ledge = null

    if current_ledge != null:
        var current_ledge_position = current_ledge.global_position
        # do something with the ledge position
```

Comment: Hey there thanks so much for the useful information and tips you have provided. and yes I have tried it with area2ds before but that's a lot of work and code duplication. if not iterated, and I've tried to iterate them with no luck because once you've passed a ledge it'd print out the every ledge area2d's position there's in existence I was succesful with this method writing it by code and adding positions one by one but no luck iterating it. so since that's the case I'm looking for the ways to implement it using raycast2ds and a ledge instead so that it makes it grabbable

Comment: I will try the Vertical Raycast shooting player up to the destination when input is pressed in the mean time if anyone knows what's wrong in the first code I'd be very much appreciated and people can see and learn from this including me myself. thanks in advance

Comment: @ab I fail to imagine how the issue you describe with the `Area2D` could have happened. About the one in your question, I don't know what you were going for. Which is why I ended up giving you alternatives. Anyway, I remind you can post your own answer once you have a solution.

Comment: so I've got area2d scenes under the game scene, that's the way we get it's position via node Path that's as far as I know. but then when we get the position of each area2d with for loop then it prints out the every global position of them unless we have an if statement above that says if you're close execute the code below and if not set it to 0. this works fine unless you can convert the NIL info to integers or vector 2 which I wasn't succesful of.

Comment: @ab I see. Well, don't do that, you don't want the player to find the area, you want the area to find the player. In particular, you want the `Area2D` to detect the player on `"body_entered"` (edit: connected to the `Area2D` itself). When the signal triggers the `Area2D` gets a signal to the object that entered. Make sure it is the player. And if it is, then call a method on it passing the `Area2D` itself, or at least the `Area2D` global position.

Comment: I've tried exactly that and it stores every ledge there's in existence when the player enters the area and figuring out which ledge was which I tried to make it only show it when player has collided with the ledge area that's smaller which's a ledge then I snapped player to desired position - with ledge's global position and when the player pressed a key then it would work flawless except it wasn't working on any other ledge except the first one

Comment: @ab That I don't understand. How is it storing them all? Where is it storing them all? There most be something I'm missing. Did you make an array? Did you connect the area to all the others (not just itself)? Is the area iterating over the other areas or something like that? Those aren't things I'd said to do, so if you did those it isn't exactly the same as I said. And I see you used `self` in the code, so that isn't the problem. Edit: when you say it didn't work with the other areas, do you mean they don't detect the player, or you got some error, or you got the wrong position, or what?

Comment: since they have uniquie positions it can't necessarily give you the position of everyone and make it work so the variable that's sent through signals actually sending info of array inside stored vector 2 location as far as I know that's, * yes I've connected them all but they teleport you to the first or whatever random or just breaks after having entered more than 1 area because it's teleporting you to the last ledge and after, the 0,0. since it's resetted to 0 in my case if not it teleports you to the whatever position random

Comment: @ab See expanded answer.

Comment: and I've tried that too made sure that it only sent the location of them only when player entered the pos, but that requires each individual variables else after the first area2d body entered it creates an array, so I could technically solve this issue by creating bunch of variables and assigning them individually but that's alotta work and is not responsive or aka I'm lazy. so I'm going to try the second approach here you've provided me

Comment: EDIT: Actually just realised you've provided a solution for that at the last paragraph. I'm going to try both when I have the time thanks so much for your efforts and time you're a gigachad